# Make a Dom element visible but don't take up space on the page?

Tags: css

What CSS will produce an element but the browser won't take it into account for laying out anything else? Is such a thing possible?

I want the bird and dog on this page to not affect the centering of the text. http://twitter-meme.appspot.com/

Some solutions that I don't like:

- Make a single image and set it as background-image. (Then I end up with a big image as a background).
- Absolutely position the text (Yuck)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `position:absolute` on the two images by setting the parent div to `position:relative` and then positioning the images to `left:0` and `right:0` respectively.

Comment: does position:relative on the parent hurt anything?

Comment: No. So long as you don't actually position the parent (with top, left, bottom or right) then it will behave as normal. position: relative is actually the default behavior but setting it explicitly allows you to absolutely position child elements to the parent instead of to the document window.

Comment: @Binarytales : exactly, though you could add left:0, top:0, right:0, or bottom:0 and they'd have no impact.

Comment: @Binarytales No, the default is behaviour is `position: static`. The main differences between the two are 1. indeed the ability to position absolutely positioned children and 2. making the element work with `z-index`s

Answer (score 2):

Make the container have position: relative; and then absolutely position the images respective to the container.

Answer (score 0):

on approach can be z-index.

It will have them floating so you can position them anywhere

Comment: `z-index` has nothing to do with positioning elements without making them take up space